# I have problems upgrading from 10.10 - The Maverick Meerkat - to latest version

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I have problems upgrading from 10.10 - The Maverick Meerkat - to latest version. I receive the message:

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I am in Copenhagen, Denmark and i can't understand why i cannot update to the latest version of Ubuntu.

I am waiting for a suggestion.Thank You.

Comment: Damn it. I am in Cracow, Poland right now and also cannot download the package!

Comment: Yes, 10.10 reached end of life back in April.

Comment: "and i can't understand why i cannot update to the latest version of Ubuntu." See psusi's comment for that ;)

Comment: What version are you trying to upgrade to? 12.10?

Comment: yes it's about upgrading to 12.10 version...

Comment: it's about upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 version (not 12.10 sorry)...but i was reading just now that this version is no longer supported. That is the reason i can't upgrade. I will install the latest version.